# Cancelling an agreement before anything has been signed

Tags: united-kingdom, deposit

In UK Law:

Is a contract still valid if it has been sent to you and has not been signed?

Can the cancellation of this contract void any terms which have been specified in the contract?

Thank you

Comment: This site is not for specific legal advice.

Comment: I've re-phrased the question @BlueDogRanch

Answer (score 1):

In English law, one of the requirements of forming a contract is the acceptance of an offer.

Since the contract was never signed (and assuming there was no acceptance of the contract communicated in some other way), we can say that this contract was never formed.

Therefore there is no legally binding agreement in place.

NB: I understand that the question may have originally contained further details, my answer only applies to the question as it stands.